# scipy.curve_fit producing [1.] as answer

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to fit the Planck's law formula to some data from SDSS (Sloan Digital Sky Survey). I've been trying this for a couple of days but I haven't been able to find a solution. Something seems to go wrong with the curve fit as the result I get is [1.], which does not seem correct. As you can also see from the graph below, Planck's law formula works as that is correct using the temperature from the Wien displacement law result. Now the problem that lies within my application of the curve fit, but I can't find the issue and any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import spectrumDataConverter as sdc
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
from scipy import constants
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

h = constants.h
c = constants.c
k = constants.k

df = sdc.spectrum("csvSpectrum.txt")                        # Getting the data (using pandas in another .py file)

def wien_model(wlPeak):                                     # The wien displacement law can be used to approximate the temperature of the star
    return ((sp.constants.Wien) / wlPeak)

def planck(wav, T):                                         # This is the correct Planck's law formula
    a = 2.0*h*c**2
    b = h*c/(wav*k*T)
    intensity = a/ ( (wav**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )
    return intensity / 1000 / 10**9                         # Converting to correct units (kW · sr⁻¹ · m⁻² · nm⁻¹) * π


bestFitPeak = df["BestFit"].max()                           # Gets the maximum value of bestfit
wlPeak = df["Wavelength"][pd.Index(df["BestFit"]).get_loc(bestFitPeak)]       # Finds the wavelength at which bestFit peaks
wlPeak = wlPeak * 10**-10                                   # Converts the wavelength from Å to m (correct unit for Wien displacement law)

approx_T = wien_model(wlPeak)                               # Gets the approximate temperature of the star (I've used this for reference only)

wavelengths = df["Wavelength"] * 10**-10                    # Converts wavelength data to m, instead of Å
       
fit = curve_fit(planck, wavelengths, (df["BestFit"] / constants.pi))         # Fitting the Planck's law model to the observed data

ans = fit[0]

intensities = planck(wavelengths, ans)                      # Calculating y-axis

plt.plot(wavelengths, intensities * constants.pi, "r-", label = str(ans))      # Plotting the fitted data
plt.plot(wavelengths, planck(wavelengths, approx_T) * constants.pi, "g-", label = str(np.round(approx_T)) + " K")
plt.plot(wavelengths, df["BestFit"], "b-", label = "Observed Data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: what range of values does `wavelengths` hold?

Comment: @DrBwts the original wavelengths are about 3500 - 9200 Å. I should probably check that I converted them to meters   :)

Comment: @DrBwts never mind, they seem to be in the correct units